# What happens after rvest submit?

Tags: web-scraping, rvest

I'm pretty new to scraping and there's something I don't get with the Rvest stuff. There's no problem with scraping a page but if I want to write some script to submit a form and then scrape the results, I don't understand it.

I mean, ok, I found the form to fill, I found the submit button, I ran the script with submit_form etc. And now what ? What should I do ? Should I get the new url (because submitting the form will bring me to a new url) ? or ... I don't know actually ?